# JS get method of object return undefenied

Tags: javascript

I created this obj:

```
const obj = {
  myVar: "123456",

  getVar: () => {
    return this.myVar;
  },

  setVar: newVal => {
    this.myVar = newVal;
  }
};
```

And when I set a new value, like this:

```
obj.setVar(666333);
```

The console prints this:

```
console.log("current value:::", obj.getVar());
// current value::: 666333
```

100% correct!

But the error happens when I try to print the initial value (123456) without set a new value before:

```
console.log("current value:::", obj.getVar());
// current value::: undefined <-- Why undefined??
// expected value: 123456
```

Where am I wrong?

Comment: You're using arrow functions when you shouldn't.

Comment: `this` isn't what you think it is. See the duplicate.

Comment: @ba_ul — It throws an exception because `this.myVar` isn't valid syntax for that part of an object literal.

Comment: As said, `this` changes meaning when used in an array function. Use normal function syntax.

Comment: `setVar: newVal => { console.log(this); ....`